# Creating a PDF programmatically on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, pdf

Hey all, was wondering if anyone could point me to the right direction.  I'm curious about how I would go about creating a PDF programmatically on the iPhone.  The documentation mentions CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider but i'm not sure how to go about using it.  Thanks!

Comment: This may not be correct but I am fairly sure that the iPhone cannot create PDFs without an external service to generate the document. Likewise I do not believe it is possible to view a PDF on the iPhone without an external service to render the output.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/RobertAPhillips/UIView_2_PDF

Answer (score 2):

*Likewise I do not believe it is possible to view a PDF on the iPhone without an external service to render the output*

This is incorrect. You can render a PDF document within a `UIWebView` instance, for example:

```
NSString *urlPathStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPDFFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlPathStr];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

You can also render a PDF within a `UIView` object for better performance.

The PDFKit library is not yet available for the iPhone.

You might look at the [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/QuartzDemo/index.html) sample application for some Quartz2D methods for rendering and manipulating a PDF document.

Answer (score 1):

CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider or CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL are the methods you have to use.

i tried this methode CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL.it will create a pdf in the url that you have provided to the methode as first parameter.

Once created ,,load the url in the web view to view the pdf.

you can enter content in pdf using cgcontextRef class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can read and store  your pdf locally in iphone application:

First create UIWebView and include <<**UIWebViewDelegate**>>

```
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourPDF.pdf"]; 
 if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
           // download file , here "https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf" = pdf downloading link
         NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf"]];
            //Store the downloaded file  in documents directory as a NSData format
         [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [yourWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [yourWebView setDelegate:self];
     yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
     [yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Or, if you simply want to read/load pdf from your Resource folder then simply do this :

```
     NSString*  filePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"pdf"]];
    /// or you can even read docs file as : pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"docx"]
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [yourWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [yourWebView setDelegate:self];
     yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
     [yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Or, if you want to create your own pdf from bunch of text and strings,here's how i did it:
  http://iosameer.blogspot.com/2012/09/creating-pdf-file-from-simple.html